# Tensorflow error using my own data on web?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new here. Now I'm learning on [tensorfly web example](https://github.com/tensorfly/tensorflow_demos)
In model forld's Model.py, I change lines 32 and 34 like this:

```
y_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
y = sess.run(y_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': imageData})
```

and final_result is my own model! I don't know about 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' and it made an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor u'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()'
```

What shonld I do? And what is that mean? Please help?

Comment: Your "final_result:0" Tensor has a shape of 1x224x224x3 in other words, you have one data row With data 244x244 large and 3 Dimensions, so maybe one 224x244 rgb Image? And you try to Feed IT an empy Tensor. Ist Hard to Teller what the actual goal is cause like that its more like you grabbing the variables oft of thin are. Also i personally prefer to use the variables them self instead of using strings. Hope this helps otherwise some further information would bei Nice and where the variables are comming frommen.

Comment: I retrain the example https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/ and got a *.pb file and I want to work it on https://github.com/tensorfly/tensorflow_demos/tree/master/tensorflow_web/model. I don't konw the 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0, please help!?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when loading the retrained model on my own data.

The problem is because the tensor `u'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` requires the string format of image input instead of numpy array. You can find out the original usage in the description of the `run_bottleneck_on_image` function.